# Rspec how to mock function call through instance method

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to test a method which uses instance variable to call featureEnabled method. I am trying to write a rspec unit test for this. I am using below setup in the allow statement. Not sure how else to do this

exception: => #<NoMethodError: undefined method `feature_enabled?' for nil:NilClass>

```
Api.controllers :Customers do
 @domain = current_account.domain

 def main
    t1 =  @domain.featureEnabled?("showPages")
    blah
```

Test:

```
RSpec.describe ApiHelpers do
    describe "#find_matching_lists" do
        let(:domain) { Domain.new }

        it "madarchod3" do
            allow(domain).to receive(:featureEnabled?).with("showPages").and_return(true)
        end
    end
```

Comment: You have to make sure `current_account.domain` returns the `domain` you're referring to with the `let`. Ex: `current_account.stub domain: domain` at the start of your example.

Answer (score 0):

Variables defined in a block are local to this block, they do not exist outside of it.

The problem you're having is that the `domain` variable you create with let is only visible inside the block passed to `describe`. Your test must be defined in that `describe` block for it to access this variable, ie this should work:

```rb
describe "#main" do
    let(:domain) { Domain.new }
    
    it "check if feature enabled" do
        allow(domain).to receive(:featureEnabled?).with("showPages").and_return(true)
    end
end
```